How do I resolve this error when invoking custom telescope pickers?
I'm trying to set up a custom buffers picker so that I just open the picker with <leader>b and then click a number that opens the desired file in the current buffer.
Code:
local actions = require("telescope.actions")
local actions_set = require("telescope.actions.set")
local actions_utils = require("telescope.actions.utils")
local builtin = require("telescope.builtin")

local function buffer_mappings(prompt_bufnr, map)
    -- delete a buffer
    map("n", "d", delete_buffer, { desc = "delete buffer" })

    -- assign number to open each buffer
    actions_utils.map_entries(prompt_bufnr, function(_, index)
        print(index)
        map("n", tostring(index), function()
            -- move upwards
            actions_set.shift_selection(prompt_bufnr, -index)
            -- open file in current buffer
            actions.select_default(prompt_bufnr)
        end)
    end)
end

-- Function to call the buffers picker with custom mappings
local function custom_buffers_picker()
    builtin.buffers({
        attach_mappings = function(prompt_bufnr, map)
            buffer_mappings(prompt_bufnr, map)
            return true
        end,
    })
end

-- Keybinding to invoke buffers picker
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>b", custom_buffers_picker, { desc = "Buffers" })

I think the problem is that the picker is not set up correctly but I'm not certain of this and I haven't managed to find away around it. I thought about environmental problems and defined these functions in different scope (i.e, in their own module) and inside config function where it resides now. I'm using lazy.nvim as a plugin manager.
The error I'm getting is:
"attempt to index field 'manager' (a boolean value)"

and the error is thrown by actions_utils.map_entries when it tries to access picker.manager.
